# Two "rows" in UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone

I need to use the extended/double row UINavigationBar instead of the default single line UINavigtationBar. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you're looking for is `prompt` on `UINavigationItem`; it's a string that you can set to get the same appearance as Safari's address bar or various pages in Settings. On a view controller, you'd use it like this:

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = @"Enter the password for “My Network”";
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I have used it before but I had forgotten the name.